# Get element's id, containing colon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to parse all error fields before saving changes, I easily can get the text of error field labels, but I stuck on getting their ids, containing colons:

```js
var x = [],
  y = [];
$('div.has-error label.control-label').each(function(index, obj) {
  x.push($(this).text());
  y.push($(this).prop('id'));
});

console.log(y.join('~'));
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3">
  <div class="ccSectionPanel panel panel-default" id="pSection3">
    <div style="cursor:pointer;" class="panel-heading" id="pSection3_heading" href="#pSection3_section" data-toggle="collapse">
      <a id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:_id145" href="#" class="panel-title">Расположение</a></div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="pSection3_section">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody">
          <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgPostCode">
              <div class="form-group required">
                <label for="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgPostCode:fieldFacet:NumberPostCode" class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="fgPostCode_label">Индекс</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                  <div id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgPostCode:fieldFacet">
                    <input type="number" value="107392" id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgPostCode:fieldFacet:NumberPostCode" name="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgPostCode:fieldFacet:NumberPostCode" autocomplete="off" class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Индекс" min="100000" pattern="^\d{6}$" max="999999" maxlength="6" required=""></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgAddress">
              <div class="form-group required">
                <label for="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgAddress:fieldFacet:TextAddress" class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="fgAddress_label">Адрес (юридический)</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                  <div id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgAddress:fieldFacet">
                    <input type="text" value="ул. Халтуринская, д.18" id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgAddress:fieldFacet:TextAddress" name="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgAddress:fieldFacet:TextAddress" autocomplete="off" class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Адрес (юридический)" required=""></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgDistrict">
              <div class="form-group required has-error has-danger">
                <label for="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgDistrict:fieldFacet:ComboDistrict" class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="fgDistrict_label">Округ</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                  <div id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgDistrict:fieldFacet">
                    <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitValidationTextBox" id="widget_view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgDistrict:fieldFacet:ComboDistrict" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" data-dojo-attach-point="_popupStateNode"
                      lang="ru" widgetid="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgDistrict:fieldFacet:ComboDistrict" aria-labelledby="fgDistrict_label" style="">
                      <div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode" role="presentation"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="button presentation" aria-hidden="true" required=""></div>
                      <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" required=""></div>
                      <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-required="true" tabindex="0" id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgDistrict:fieldFacet:ComboDistrict"
                          value="" aria-invalid="false" required=""><input type="hidden" name="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgDistrict:fieldFacet:ComboDistrict" value=""></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgArea">
              <div class="form-group required has-error has-danger">
                <label for="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgArea:fieldFacet:ComboArea" class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="fgArea_label">Район</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                  <div id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgArea:fieldFacet">
                    <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitValidationTextBox" id="widget_view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgArea:fieldFacet:ComboArea" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" data-dojo-attach-point="_popupStateNode"
                      lang="ru" widgetid="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgArea:fieldFacet:ComboArea" aria-labelledby="fgArea_label" style="">
                      <div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode" role="presentation"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="button presentation" aria-hidden="true" required=""></div>
                      <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" required=""></div>
                      <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-required="true" tabindex="0" id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgArea:fieldFacet:ComboArea"
                          value="" aria-invalid="false" required=""><input type="hidden" name="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgArea:fieldFacet:ComboArea" value=""></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get a list of id's, containing colons (to create links on error blocks)?

Comment: have you tried the  dojo ? somehting like dojo.forEach(dojo.query("div.has-error label.control-label"),function(label){console.log(label.id);});

Comment: Not entirely clear which ID you need and what is wrong with the `y` array currently or what specific problem really is

Comment: IBM Domino uses old Dojo and it's not very compatible with the jQuery. I had the "y" array empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get attribute "id" of that element,

Please check fiddle I made for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/p1c0s45r/1/

```
<div id="view:_id1:_id2:facetMiddle:ccSection3:panelBody:fgDistrict"></div>

<span></span>

  $(document).ready(function() {

        $('span').html($('div').attr('id'));

    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try. I've changed the logic, gettin' parentNodes and collectin' their id's. I need something to jump from the list of invalidated fields and decided to jump on a parent container.